# Find length of time within range

Tags: excel, if-statement, time

I'm trying to understand length of an outage that occurs within time range.

In once cell I have the support period: Level 1 `Monday-Saturday 0800-1800`

In two other cells I have the start time and end time of the outage

Example:
Outage Start: `Wednesday, 24 August 2016 16:47`

Outage End: `Monday, 29 August 2016 10:15`

Result should return: `33:28` hours
Workings:

```
Wednesday, 24 August 2016 16:47 - 18:00 = + 01:13
Thursday , 25 August 2016 08:00 - 18:00 = + 10:00
Friday   , 26 August 2016 08:00 - 18:00 = + 10:00
Saturday , 27 August 2016 08:00 - 18:00 = + 10:00
Monday   , 29 August 2016 08:00 - 10:15 = + 02:15
```

Any advice appreciated!

**Updated**

Comment: usually it's something like `= ( A1 - A2 ) / 24` but `13:00 Monday` does not seem like a valid date because it does not show any date/month/year

Comment: Sorry updated cell values

Comment: actually, how do you get only 15 hours if the difference between the two dates is 4 days, 17 hours and 28 minutes ?

Comment: Sorry corrected with workings

Comment: Thanks for the workings and the time specifications, I'm not sure my answer is relevant any more, but it looks like @Karpak has a good answer

Answer (score 1):

[image: Sample Excel]

Please check the above image, I hope you want something similar to this.

Enter the following formula in the column C2

```
=INT(IF(DAYS(B2,A2)=0,IF(TEXT(A2,"ddd")="Sun",0,ROUND((B2-A2)/(1/24/60),0)
  ),IF(DAYS(B2,A2)=1,IF(TEXT(A2,"ddd")="Sun",0,(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))+1/24*18)-A2
     )/(1/24/60) +
     IF(TEXT(B2,"ddd")="Sun",0,B2-(DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))+1/24*8)
       )/(1/24/60),IF(TEXT(A2,"ddd")="Sun",0,(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))+1/24*18)-A2
     )/(1/24/60) +
     IF(TEXT(B2,"ddd")="Sun",0,B2-(DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))+1/24*8)
       )/(1/24/60) +
      (IF(DAYS((DATE(YEAR(B2-1),MONTH(B2-1),DAY(B2-1))),A2)<0,0,DAYS((DATE(YEAR(B2-1),MONTH(B2-1),DAY(B2-1))),A2))-
         INT(((DATE(YEAR(B2-1),MONTH(B2-1),DAY(B2-1)))-(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)) + MOD(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)),7)))/7+1)) * 10 * 60
  )
))
```

Enter the following formula in the cell D2

```
=INT(C2/60) &":" & INT(MOD(C2,60)+0.5)
```

Then copy the C2 and D2 to all the cells that you want, it will give the outage value that you are looking for.

Comment: @Georgemichaels: Can you please update whether this works for you?

Answer (score 0):

For example if cell `A2` contains the Outage Start date `Wednesday, 24 August 2016 16:47` and cell `B2` contains the Outage End date `Monday, 29 August 2016 10:15`, then you can use the following:

```
=DAY(B2-A2)
```

This will return 4 days.

```
=HOUR(B2-A2)
```

Will return 17 hours

```
=MINUTE(B2-A2)
```

Will return 28 minutes.

Then you could use the following:

```
="The outage lasted for "& DAY(B2-A2) & " days, " & HOUR(B2-A2) & " hours, and " & MINUTE(B2-A2) & " minutes."
```

To produce this:

> The outage lasted for 4 days, 17 hours, and 28 minutes.

Comment: It seems that only the hours that were in the `Monday-Saturday 0800-1800` window are needed, but I still can't figure out how to get 15 hours from it ( unless they have a very big launch break :] ). You can check the comments in my answer if you are willing to give it a shot.

Comment: Ahhhh, yes, that would have been a valuable additional piece of info.  :D Looks like @Karpak has it under control now.

Comment: @Slai Thanks for your follow up work on this, good work getting to the root of the problem!  :D